# Edit record employee on text file using Vectors in Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to edit a string which is already on a text file using vectors in Java? For example, the user inputs the employee number asked by the program and then the user will input the name and age. The modified info will be updated to the text file which serves as employee records.

Comment: There's a lot of ways to do this. Your question is too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vector is just a data structure. It cannot be used to read/write employee records from/into files. It can, however, be used to keep employee records in memory.

To implement the functionality that you need, you need to:

1. Think on how the employee records are represented in file. Is it in CSV? XML? JSON?
2. Once you decide the representation, you need to write two methods. One that reads the file, and returns employee records in a Vector. Two that accepts employee records, and write them into file.
3. Write the main program that operates on this Vector.